# Building GDAL for Macos with CMake does not work

Tags: cmake, gdal

I want to build GDAL for MacOS with Java bindings. The problem is that CMake does not find includes under cmake/helpers. I get the following error:

-- Performing Test HAS_NO_UNDEFINED - Failed
CMake Error at frmts/zlib/contrib/infback9/CMakeLists.txt:13 (include):
include could not find requested file:
GdalDriverHelper

I cloned the GDAL repository and made a subfolder "build" under the root directory of the project. I also installed some required dependencies with brew install name_of_module.

After the preparations, I tried running "cmake .." in the build directory. I also tried different arguments for cmake, but every time I get the error.

If I edit CMakeLists.txt under frmts/zlib/contrib and insert set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /Users/xxxx/work/gdal/gdal/cmake/helpers), the build works for zlib. However, then I get an error for the next dependency. How can I configure the build?

I expected that the build should work just by calling cmake .. in the build directory. The documentation indicates it should work this way.

Comment: what version of GDAL is this? what version of CMake do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

### Edit: Better Solution

Configure the GDAL build to skip the find_package invocation of arrow - deleting the Arrow config is not necessary. Disable libkml the same as below:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_DISABLE_FIND_PACKAGE_Arrow=ON -DGDAL_USE_LIBKML=OFF ..
```

### Original Solution

This will still work (and provides some useful background), but the above solution is better.

#### Short Answer:

Try deleting Arrow from cmake:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/cmake/Arrow
```

Then running the build with the following flags (from the build directory):

```
cmake .. \
        -DGDAL_USE_GEOTIFF_INTERNAL=ON \
        -DGDAL_USE_PNG_INTERNAL=ON \
        -DGDAL_USE_POSTGRESQL=OFF \
        -DGDAL_USE_WEBP=OFF \
        -DGDAL_USE_ARROW=OFF \
        -DGDAL_USE_PARQUET=OFF \
        -DGDAL_USE_LIBKML=OFF \
        -DBUILD_CSHARP_BINDINGS=OFF
```

#### Background

I originally found this question because I had the same issue. I eventually found this solution by picking apart the macOS build configuration in the GDAL cmake_build.yml GitHub actions workflow file. In particular, [this step on line 592](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/.github/workflows/cmake_builds.yml#L592) seems to be the key:

```
# Remove broken Arrow as it causes CMake detection issue
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/cmake/Arrow
```

The brew commands just above this line may also be relevant, depending on what you have installed already.

That got me past this failure, but then I hit a series of other issues.
Using [some of the CMAKE_OPTIONS from line 560](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/.github/workflows/cmake_builds.yml#L560) (as listed above) eventually got the build to work for me.

#### System Info

All this was run against the GDAL 3.7.0 checkout, on macOS 13.5, with the AppleClang 14.0.3.14030022 C compiler